# How to disable notifications for all Facebook events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events, facebook-notifications

Facebook is constantly pestering me with updates from events I'm signed up to. Is there a way to completely disable those notifications?

I know it's possible to manually click "Stop Notifications" on each event but it's very annoying.